# Android studio prevent code reformatting on paste

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've started using Android Studio (replacing Eclipse) and one thing I just can't get used to is how Studio automatically (under certain circumstances) reformats some or even all of my code in the current file.  One of those circumstances is pasting text into my file.  when I do that, the entire block gets reformatted according to the arcane rules I can format (but seriously do not like) in the Settings.

Is there a check box somewhere in the settings that turns this off??

I can format my own code easily enough, and since I can also manually tell Studio to "do it now", there doesn't seem to be any reason to put up with all the automatic hand-holding.

Comment: That's a super feature, since most people on the internet do not understand what code fornatting is.

Comment: You wanted the bycicle? Now pedal!!

Comment: Actually, I did not.  Android just helpfully stopped supporting features we needed in Eclipse.

Comment: Bojan, please tell me that was sarcasm....

Comment: Well... I'm still using Eclipse. And it still works **perfectly fine**. Why doesn't it for you?

Comment: @Rich I have provided an answer, tough I recommend you not turning it off, instead using the temporary option when you don't want it to be formatted.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I prefer vim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can stop it by setting the **Reformat on paste** option to none to **None**. You can find the option under **Editor -> General -> Smart Keys**. See the image

[image]

You can temporary disable reformat by pasting the code by pressing **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + V**

Alternatly you can right click on where you want to paste the code and then click **Paste simple**

[image]

Comment: Well, at least I know how to toggle it on and off, so if the solution proves worse than the problem at least I can undo that.   Thanks.

Comment: I think the fact that an operation that contains the word "Simple" in Android Studio requires "Ctrl+Alt+Shift" tells you most of what you need to know about working in this tool.