# Android studion: Disable auto formatting of line comments

Tags: android, android-studio, autoformatting

I've recently started working with Android studio, and while I like the auto-formatter and use it often for whole files (The Ctrl+Alt+L thing), there's one thing that I would like to disable:

Sometimes I comment a code line like this:

```
doSomething(); // This is some side-comment
               // that might span over 2 lines.
```

I would like the comment to stay as is, but the auto-formatter will turn it into:

```
doSomething(); // This is some side-comment
// that might span over 2 lines.
```

Is there a way to prevent this while keeping all the other auto-formatter goodies intact? I couldn't find any code-style setting that controls the indentation of comments.
Is there perhaps a way to add a custom rule to the auto formatter?

Comment: Settings>Editor>Java/javaDoc and play around with the settings u like

Comment: @k0sh: Thanks, I just tried all the options there, but non of them worked to solve my problem. I couldn't affect the auto-formatting of my second line of the comment. (Using Android studio 1.2.2)

Comment: hmm, anyway zohar, i'd recommend to comment docs as /***/ you could have control over it ..

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is caused by either Ctrl-Alt-L (manually) or automatically when you paste text.

Preventing the latter is described here:

[Android studio prevent code reformatting on paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487067/android-studio-prevent-code-reformatting-on-paste)

So, setting "Reformat on paste" to "none" should do the trick.